# csv import of images does not work reliably

Tags: image, csv, ce-1.9.1.0, importexport

**I am trying to import products with images into magento via a csv file.** However, most of the  times, the images are not imported, neither in the frontend nor the backend.

I use columns `"image", "small_image", "thumbnail"` which all contain e.g. **"/1.jpg"**

For a certain product, where the image is in a file `"/var/www/media/import/1.jpg`", the values "image_label", "small_image_label", "thumbnail_label" are kept empty.

**No matter what I do, the images are not appearing regularly for the products.**

If I try several times, it works sometimes, I think with a higher probability if I use a small number of products.

What can the problem be and is there a method for importing images which works reliably?

Edit:
I use `import/export`. Some lines from my `csv` file:

```
sku,name,price,image,small_image,thumbnail,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,_media_image,_media_lable,_media_position,_media_is_disabled,_type,_attribute_set,_product_websites,description,short_description,weight,status,visibility,tax_class_id,qty,_media_attribute_id

---newline---

12412849,Produkt1,20.35,/12412849.jpg,/12412849.jpg,/12412849.jpg,,,,/12412849.jpg,,1,0,simple,Default,base,Default,Default,0,1,4,2,76,77

---newline---

10532469,Produkt2,27.75,/220x220/10532469.jpg,/220x220/10532469.jpg,/220x220/10532469.jpg,,,,/220x220/10532469.jpg,,1,0,simple,Default,base,Default,Default,0,1,4,2,76,77
```

Comment: Well there should not be any probability, it either works or it doesn't. Anyway the information you provided is not specific enough. Are you using old (dataflow) or new import/export. Can you give us a few lines from CSV as an example?

Answer (score 0):

Also this way, you can import product images via CSV : "https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/05/importing-product-images-via-csv-in-magento-1-7-0-0/"

Answer (score 0):

If your server's a Linux one, it can be case sensitive, therefore make sure you're taking into account the case of the URL string in the CSV eg.

"/var/www/media/import/foldername/subfolder/1.jpg"

when it should be,

"/var/www/media/import/**F**oldername/**S**ub**F**older/1.jpg" - just as an example. You'd know exactly what it is by looking in the FTP.

ensure that the url that's in your csv matches exactly what's in the FTP.

Also make your permissions 777 for the relevant folders.